# How to Reopen pure CSS3 modal dialog

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, html, css

I have following Modal Dialog (popup) using **only CSS3** in my asp page for user registration:
**HTML :**

```
<%-- Modal PopUp starts here--%>
<div id="openModal" class="modalDialog">
    <div>   <a href="#close" title="Close" class="close" onclick="DisableAllPopUpTxt()">X</a>

        <table style="width:100%;">
            <tr>
                <td style="text-align: center; width: 100%;"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="text-align: center; width: 100%;">
                    <asp:Label ID="lblErrorMSG2" runat="server" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#FF3300" Text="Email ID Already Taken " Visible="False"></asp:Label>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="text-align: center; width: 100%;">
                    <input id="txtCustFName" name="txtCustFName" type="text" required placeholder="Enter Your First Name" style="width: 80%" />
                </td>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="text-align: center; width: 100%;">
                    <input id="txtCustLName" name="txtCustLName" type="text" required placeholder="Enter Your Last Name" style="width: 80%" />
                </td>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="text-align: center; width: 100%;">
                    <input id="txtCustREmail" name="txtCustREmail" type="email" required placeholder="Enter Valid Email ID" style="width: 80%" />
                </td>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="text-align: center; width: 100%;">
                    <input id="txtCustRPwd" name="txtCustRPwd" type="password" required placeholder="Enter Password" style="width: 80%" />
                </td>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="text-align: center; width: 100%;">
                    <input id="txtCustRePwd" name="txtCustRePwd" type="password" required placeholder="ReType Password" style="width: 80%" />
                </td>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="text-align: center; width: 100%;">
                    <input id="txtCustPh" name="txtCustPh" type="number" size="10" min="10" max="10" required placeholder="Enter Valid Mobile No" style="width: 80%" />
                </td>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="style1" style="text-align: center; width: 100%;" onclick="btnSignUp()">
                    <asp:Button ID="btnSingUp" runat="server" onclick="signUp" Text="Login" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="text-align: center; width: 100%;"> </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
<%--Modal PopUp Ends Here--%>
```

**CSS :**

```
.modalDialog {
    position: fixed;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
    z-index: 99999;
    opacity:0;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
    -moz-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
    transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
    pointer-events: none;
    }

.modalDialog:target {
    opacity:1;
    pointer-events: auto;
    }

.modalDialog > div {
    width: 400px;
    position: relative;
    margin: 10% auto;
    padding: 5px 20px 13px 20px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background: #fff;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(#fff, #999);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#fff, #999);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(#fff, #999);
    }

.close {
    background: #606061;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    line-height: 25px;
    position: absolute;
    right: -12px;
    text-align: center;
    top: -10px;
    width: 24px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;
    -webkit-border-radius: 12px;
    -moz-border-radius: 12px;
    border-radius: 12px;
    -moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;}
.close:hover { background: #00d9ff; 
               }
```

In my asp page I've following **anchor tag** which is used to display the popup:

**Register**

Now the problem is:

As this is registration form, I want server side validation of existing email id .
If user entered email id already exist in DB I want to reopen the above modal dialog with an error message Email ID already exist.

I m not able to reopen that dialog box.
Is there any way to do this using js?
Plz help me.

The tutorial for modal dialog is on site:
[click here](http://www.webdesignerdepot.com/2012/10/creating-a-modal-window-with-html5-and-css3/)

For visualizing modal dialog:
[click here](http://www.flickr.com/photos/95565062@N06/8715526791/)

Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 0):

for server side validation I suggest you to use javascript web method for this. By using this web method your popup didn't close while page check server side validation.....

Answer (score 0):

Change the :target to also accept a class:

```
.modalDialog:target, .modalDialog.target {
  opacity:1;
  pointer-events: auto;
}
```

And then when you find out the email is invalid, you can just do:

```
$('.modalDialog').addClass('target')
```

or the non-jquery equivalent.